# Edges created via knife tool cuts in Blender visible in object mode?

Tags: mesh, edges, topology, knife-tool

It's my first time posting on stack exchange so excuse me if I overlook some common courtesy with this post. I'm pretty knew to Blender, about a month in, and I'm working on retopologizing a mesh so I can UV unwrap it (and yes the topology is terrible lol.) I was creating some new faces with the knife tool when I realized, for some reason I could see the edges of these new faces made with the knife tool in object mode. I figure that can't be good and will cause some undesired effect later. I'm using Blender 4.0, thank you ahead of time for any help!

Here you can faintly see the edges from the knife tool in solid view object mode.
[image: Object Mode]

Just for reference here's edit mode
[image: Edit Mode]

Comment: Not sure with the .blend unavailable (and even then probably wouldn't be sure) but I think it's just a bug/limitation of the outline rendering, where it gets confused in certain situations… Maybe related to scale/camera settings causing some float precision errors... 

Comment: Hi! Welcome to BSE. It is good that you wrote that it is your first posting and that you are a Blender beginner. You showed us your topology via images (which is good) and i am assuming that you have double vertices. The word "assuming" means, i am not sure. So i think it is a good idea if you provide a blend file so we can check it out. You can provide a blend file via opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady So after messing around more I realized it was just a rookie mistake, I was connecting vertices across existing faces so it was creating new faces in the exact same position. There's probably some way to set the normals of both faces the same way and have them merge or something but for now I've just deleted the larger flat face and used extrusions and loop cuts to re create the mesh in those areas and create the face AFTER all the vertices are in place and connect. Thanks for the reply and if you know a less hands on way to do this would love to hear it!

Comment: Also can I upload the blend file directly to stack or does it need to be hosted somewhere else?

Comment: [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486) - perhaps all you needed to do is select all, then merge by distance? In Edit Mode, keys A, M, B in that order.